# How to work with UTF-8 in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, encoding

I just want to get UTF-8 working. I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

t = "одобрение за"
print t
```

But when I run this program from the command line, output looks like: ╨╛╨┤╨╛╨▒╤Ç╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╡ ╨╖╨░

I've searched up and down the net, tried the whole sys.setdefaultencoding thing, tried calling encode() and decode(), tried placing the little "u" in front, tried unicode(), etc.

I'm about ready to explode from frustration. Is there a definitive answer for what the heck you're supposed to do?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: What's the encoding of your *terminal*? Did you check `sys.stdout.encoding`? The fact that your string is a unicode string does *not* mean that the terminal is able to display it correctly.

Comment: Are you running this from Windows using `cmd.exe`?

Comment: You forgot to add `u` to "одобрение за". Try this: t = **u**"одобрение за"

Comment: @stalk Is that necessary?

Comment: Of course! Without this `u` you will have just a sequence of bytes, encoded in utf8 (because you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of file) in variable `t`. And with `u` you'll have a sequence of unicode code points. So, without `u`, code `print "одобрение за"` is equivalent to `print u"одобрение за".encode('utf8')`. And last one is the same, as `print "\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0"

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me (tm)

```
In [1]: t = u"одобрение за"

In [2]: print t
одобрение за
```

Make sure your terminal supports UTF-8. One way is to check the `LANG` env-variable:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

also, try the `locale` command.

`$LANG/locale` just tells you what your system will use when writing to stdout/stderr. 
Best way to test if terminal supports UTF-8 is probably to print something to it and see if it looks correct. Something like this:

```
echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
```

You should get a `€`-sign.

If not, try a different shell...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows `cmd.exe`, you have to follow two steps:

1. Make sure your console is using Lucidia console font family (other fonts cannot display UTF-8 properly).
2. Type `chcp 65001` (that's `ch`ange `c`ode`p`age) and hit enter.
3. Run your command.

For subsequent runs (once you close the `cmd.exe` window), you'll have to change the codepage again. The font should be permanent.

Comment: "LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001"

Comment: Uh, where did you type that?  Do you have UTF-8 enabled in languages and settings/regions or whatever is called in the control panel? You'll also need to enable "advanced support" which will install other files to provide support for all programs.

Comment: I am using W7 so I don't see that option

Comment: Hmm, in Windows 7 UTF is enabled by default, but you may need a font. Try opening up PowerShell (should be installed by default), and then type this `$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding` and then run your script again.